# どうして、この出力になるのか教えてください。

Tags: java

```
package chapter04;

public class IncDec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10, b = 10, c = 0, d = 0;

        System.out.println("a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c + " d:" + d);

        c = a--;
        d = ++b;
        System.out.println("\nc = a--; d = ++b;");
        System.out.println("a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c + " d:" + d);

        c = --a;
        d = b++;
        System.out.println("\nc = --a; d = b++;");
        System.out.println("a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c + " d:" + d);

        d = ++a - b--;
        System.out.println("\nd = ++a - b--;");
        System.out.println("a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c + " d:" + d);

        a--;
        ++b;
        System.out.println("\na--; ++b;");
        System.out.println("a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c + " d:" + d);
    }

}
```

＜出力＞

```
a:10 b:10 c:0 d:0

c = a--; d = ++b;
a:9 b:11 c:10 d:11

c = --a; d = b++;
a:8 b:12 c:8 d:11

d = ++a - b--;
a:9 b:11 c:8 d:-3

a--; ++b;
a:8 b:12 c:8 d:-3
```

Comment: 詳しい人が見れば回答を付けることは可能だと思いますが、ご自身で「どの部分に疑問を抱いているのか」を質問文に含める必要があると思います(このままだと単に"質問の丸投げ"という印象を与えます)。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

出力の各行について説明します。

```
a:10 b:10 c:0 d:0
```

初期状態です。

```
c = a--; d = ++b;
a:9 b:11 c:10 d:11
```

cにaの後置デクリメント、dにbの前置インクリメントを代入しています。後置では代入してから評価、前置では評価してから代入が行われるため、 `cにaを代入して（c=10）からaをデクリメント（a=9）`、`bをインクリメントして（b=11）からdに代入`しています。

```
c = --a; d = b++;
a:8 b:12 c:8 d:11
```

同様に、cにaの前置デクリメント、dにbの後置インクリメントを代入しています。

```
d = ++a - b--;
a:9 b:11 c:8 d:-3
```

これはパターンが変わり、dに（aの前置インクリメントからbの後置デクリメントを引いたもの）を代入しています。評価の順番は「aがインクリメントされ（aが9になる）、dにa-bが代入され（dが9-12=-3になる）、bがデクリメントされる（bが11になる）」という流れになります。

```
a--; ++b;
a:8 b:12 c:8 d:-3
```

aが後置デクリメント、bが前置インクリメントされます。代入はありませんが、aが8、bが12になっています。

前置と後置についてはこの記事が参考になるかと存じます。
[前置と後置 - 演算子 - Java入門](https://www.javadrive.jp/start/ope/index7.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。とてもわかりやすく、URLまでご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Comment: この回答でよろしければ[解決としてマーク]をお願いします。

Comment: マークとは✅マークでよろしかったですか？